# Add marker on leaflet when selecting from filter in flexdashboard for R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am quit new to R and trying to develop an dashboard with Flexdashboard based on this example:
https://matt-dray.github.io/earl18-crosstalk/04_leaflet-flexdash-dt-crosstalk.html

I get it to work, but what I am trying to accomplish is that I don't want all my points to show on at the start.
When a user selects a filter I want to add a marker to the map and zoom to this point. I am not using the datatables element

The code I have so far

````
    ---
title: "Leaflet + Flexdashboard + DT + Crosstalk"
author: "Matt Dray"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: paper
    favicon: img/ios7-location-outline.png
    source_code: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# prep workspace
library(dplyr)  # tidy data manipulation
library(leaflet)  # interative mapping
library(DT)  # interactive tables
library(crosstalk)  # inter-widget interactivity
library(varhandle) # change column type
sch <- readRDS("data/gias_sample.RDS")
#sch <- readRDS("data/grafinformatie.rds")
#sch <- as.data.frame(sch)
#sch <- unfactor(sch) # change column type
sd <- SharedData$new(sch)
```

Interactives {data-icon="ion-stats-bars"}
=====================================  

Column {data-width=400}
-------------------------------------

### Filters

```{r filters}
filter_select(
  id = "geo_la",
  label = "NAME",
  sharedData = sd,
  group = ~geo_la
)


```


Column {data-width=600}
-------------------------------------

### Interactive map

```{r map}
sd %>% 
  leaflet::leaflet() %>%
  leaflet::addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)
  # leaflet::addAwesomeMarkers(
  #   icon = awesomeIcons(
  #     library = "ion",
  #     iconColor = "white"
  #   )
  # ) %>%   # end addAwesomeMarkers()
  #leaflet::addMeasure()
```

$(document).ready(function () {
  FlexDashboard.init({
    theme: "paper",
    fillPage: true,
    orientation: "columns",
    storyboard: false,
    defaultFigWidth: 576,
    defaultFigHeight: 460,
    defaultFigWidthMobile: 360,
    defaultFigHeightMobile: 460
  });
});
````

Hope someone can help! Thanks